# C++ DLL Plugin thread runs slow on Win 10

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, dll, windows-10-universal

I've created a threaded DLL to read a serial port. This DLL is a plugin for VBS2. If I run the application in Windows 7 it works perfectly, however if I run the same plugin on a Windows 10 machine it slows down and lags approx. 5 seconds behind. Is there a new way to create a thread in Windows 10 that I do not know about?

here's my code for the plugin below

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "VBSPlugin.h"
#include <string>       // used for sprintf_s
#include "Serial.h"     //  used for serial com port connection

#include <thread>


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

float X = 0.0;
float Y = 0.0;
float Z = 0.0;

int B1 = 0;
int B2 = 0;
int B3 = 0;
int B4 = 0;
int B5 = 0;
int Calibrating = 0;     // int sent from head-tracker

float InitX = 0.0;
float InitY = 0.0;
float InitZ = 0.0;

float HEADING_OFF = 0.0;


//control varibles
bool connected = false;
int   Data_Of_Thread_1;
CSerial serial;





DWORD WINAPI SerialThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{


    bool synced = false;

    string dataString;

    char* buffer = new char[1]();

    while (true){

        if (serial.IsOpened()){

            serial.ReadData(buffer, 1);

            if (_stricmp("<", buffer) == 0)
            {
                synced = true;

            };

            if (((_stricmp("\r", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("\n", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("<", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp(">", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp(",", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp(".", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("-", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("1", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("2", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("3", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("4", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("5", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("6", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("7", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("8", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("9", buffer) == 0) || (_stricmp("0", buffer) == 0)) && synced == true)
            {
                dataString += buffer;

                if ((_stricmp(">", buffer) == 0))
                {
                    // end of packet
                    synced = false;
                    cout << "dataString: " << dataString << std::endl;
                    /*vector<string> x = split(dataString, ',');

                    LB_STATUS->SetLabel(dataString);

                    try {
                    X = stof(x[1]);
                    Y = stof(x[2]);
                    Z = stof(x[3]);
                    B1 = stoi(x[4]);
                    B2 = stoi(x[5]);
                    B3 = stoi(x[6]);
                    B4 = stoi(x[7]);
                    B5 = stoi(x[8]);
                    Calibrating = stoi(x[9]);

                    }
                    catch (...) {

                    };
                    */
                    dataString.clear();
                };

            }
            else
            {
                ;;
            }
        }

        else{

            cout << "Not Connected" << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}





// Command function declaration
typedef int (WINAPI * ExecuteCommandType)(const char *command, char *result, int resultLength);

// Command function definition
ExecuteCommandType ExecuteCommand = NULL;

// Function that will register the ExecuteCommand function of the engine
VBSPLUGIN_EXPORT void WINAPI RegisterCommandFnc(void *executeCommandFnc)
{
  ExecuteCommand = (ExecuteCommandType)executeCommandFnc;
}

// This function will be executed every simulation step (every frame) and took a part in the simulation procedure.
// We can be sure in this function the ExecuteCommand registering was already done.
// deltaT is time in seconds since the last simulation step
VBSPLUGIN_EXPORT void WINAPI OnSimulationStep(float deltaT)
{
  //{ Sample code:

  //!}
}



const char *sendX(const char *input)
{
    // adjust 0-360 degrees to input offset

    X = X + HEADING_OFF;
    if (X > 360)  { X = X - 360; };


    // The output result
    static char result[256];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%f']", X);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
};
const char *sendY(const char *input)
{
    // The output result
    static char result[256];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%f']", Y);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
}
const char *sendZ(const char *input)
{
    // The output result
    static char result[256];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%f']", Z);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
}
const char *sendA(const char *input)
{
    // adjust 0-360 degrees to input offset
    X = X + HEADING_OFF;
    if (X > 360)  { X = X - 360; };

    // The output result
    static char result[256];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%i,%i,%i']", X, Y, Z);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
}
const char *sendB1(const char *input)
{
    // The output result
    static char result[256];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%i']", B1);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
}
const char *sendB2(const char *input)
{
    // The output result
    static char result[512];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%i']", B2);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
}
const char *sendB3(const char *input)
{
    // The output result
    static char result[512];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%i']", B3);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
}
const char *sendB4(const char *input)
{
    // The output result
    static char result[512];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%i']", B4);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
}
const char *sendB5(const char *input)
{
    // The output result
    static char result[512];

    sprintf_s(result, "['%i']", B5);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return result;
}

const char *CALIBRATE(const char *input)
{
    //int nBytesSent = serial.SendData("1", 1);

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return NULL;
}
const char *CONNECT(const char *input)
{
    if (serial.Open(5, 115200)){
        connected = true;
    }
    /*Hthread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, XYZ, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);
    if (Hthread1 == NULL)
    {

    LB_STATUS->SetLabel("Status: Failed to open thread!");
    }
    else
    {
    btnDisConnect->Enable();
    btnConnect->Disable();
    btnCalib->Enable();     // disable the calibration button

    }*/

    return NULL;
}
const char *DISCONNECT(const char *input)
{
    if (serial.Close()){
        connected = false;
    }

    // Return whatever is in the result
    return NULL;
}




// This function will be executed every time the script in the engine calls the script function "pluginFunction"
// We can be sure in this function the ExecuteCommand registering was already done.
// Note that the plugin takes responsibility for allocating and deleting the returned string
VBSPLUGIN_EXPORT const char* WINAPI PluginFunction(const char *input)
{
    static const char cmdX[] = "X";
    static const char cmdY[] = "Y";
    static const char cmdZ[] = "Z";
    static const char cmdXYZ[] = "A";
    static const char cmdB1[] = "B1";
    static const char cmdB2[] = "B2";
    static const char cmdB3[] = "B3";
    static const char cmdB4[] = "B4";
    static const char cmdB5[] = "B5";
    static const char cmdCONNECT[] = "CONNECT"; //show the GUI window
    static const char cmdDISCONNECT[] = "DISCONNECT";   //show the GUI window
    static const char cmdCALIBRATE[] = "CALIBRATE"; //show the GUI window



    // _strnicmp returns 0 (which is TRUE when using this command) if strings X == Y up to the character length of X, so Toss==Toss, Toss==Tossy, etc.
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdX, strlen(cmdX)) == 0) return sendX(&input[strlen(cmdX)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdY, strlen(cmdY)) == 0) return sendY(&input[strlen(cmdY)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdZ, strlen(cmdZ)) == 0) return sendZ(&input[strlen(cmdZ)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdXYZ, strlen(cmdXYZ)) == 0) return sendA(&input[strlen(cmdXYZ)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdB1, strlen(cmdB1)) == 0) return sendB1(&input[strlen(cmdB1)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdB2, strlen(cmdB2)) == 0) return sendB2(&input[strlen(cmdB2)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdB3, strlen(cmdB3)) == 0) return sendB3(&input[strlen(cmdB3)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdB4, strlen(cmdB4)) == 0) return sendB4(&input[strlen(cmdB4)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdB5, strlen(cmdB5)) == 0) return sendB5(&input[strlen(cmdB5)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdCONNECT, strlen(cmdCONNECT)) == 0) return CONNECT(&input[strlen(cmdCONNECT)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdDISCONNECT, strlen(cmdDISCONNECT)) == 0) return DISCONNECT(&input[strlen(cmdDISCONNECT)]);
    if (_strnicmp(input, cmdCALIBRATE, strlen(cmdCALIBRATE)) == 0) return CALIBRATE(&input[strlen(cmdCALIBRATE)]);

    // Report error; should return in VBS2 as ["{error} Unrecognized command"] -- string in an array
    static const char err[] = "['Unrecognized command Use X,Y,Z,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,A,SHOW,CONNECT']";

    return err;
}

// DllMain
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
   switch(fdwReason)
   {
   case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
   {
                              AllocConsole();
                              freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
                              HANDLE   Hthread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SerialThread, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);


   }
         OutputDebugString("Called DllMain with DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH\n");
         break;
      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
         OutputDebugString("Called DllMain with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH\n");
         break;
      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
         OutputDebugString("Called DllMain with DLL_THREAD_ATTACH\n");
         break;
      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
         OutputDebugString("Called DllMain with DLL_THREAD_DETACH\n");
         break;
   }
   return TRUE;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Although the question might be answerable without looking at the code at all, can you please condense it to a mcve?

Comment: What is VBS2?  It's not in my acronym dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, what is MCVE? VBS2 is a first person simulator for military training. It has its own ASI that you can plug into to provide your own functions